# Accessing value from adf declarative component method

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf, custom-component

I have a declarative component in which I have a link, on click of a link I invoke an action listener and I map this action listener to my Main Application managed bean but I keep getting error on click of link

```
<MethodExpressionActionListener> <processAction> Received 'javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException' when invoking action listener '#{comp.handleTreeNodeClick}' for component 'dc_cl1'
<MethodExpressionActionListener> <processAction> javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Application2/ViewControllerWebApp.war/Home.jsf @14,92 TreeNodeClick="#{backingBeanScope.Home.navigationTreeLinkClicked.execute}": The class 'view.backing.Home' does not have the property 'navigationTreeLinkClicked'.
```

The following is my code.

1. My declarative component

   ```
    <af:commandLink text="#{node.CONTENT_NAME}" id="dc_cl1"
                    inlineStyle="height:inherit; width:150px;" 
                    actionListener="#{comp.handleTreeNodeClick}">

        <f:attribute name="param" value="#{node.CONTENT_URL}"/>                
    </af:commandLink>
   ```
2. I have a string value in `#{node.CONTENT_URL}`
3. `TreeNodeClick` is the method I created at time of creating my declarative comp
4. I bound this method to my link action listener
5. Also added a parameter in `<f:attribute>`
6. signature of this method is `TreeNodeClick(javax.faces.event)`

Now I consume this in my main app and map this func to  void `getNavigationTreeLinkClicked(ActionEvent actionEvent)`
this method is present in my Main App bean class.

I want to access that **param value** but I keep getting error as stated above.

My `getNavigationTreeLinkClicked()` method body is as follow

```
public void getNavigationTreeLinkClicked(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    System.out.println("node clicked");
    String param = (String) actionEvent.getComponent().getAttributes().get("param");  
    System.out.println(param);
}
```

but as my error suggest my component `TreeNodeClicked` func is not getting mapped to `navigationTreeLinkClicked`.
please help me resolve this error and also how can I fetch that param value.

Answer (score 0):

Your Action Listener method name is incorrect. It should be:

```
public void navigationTreeLinkClicked(ActionEvent actionEvent) {...}
```

Comment: are you refering to navigationTreeLinkClicked() and getNavigationTreeLinkClicked()

Comment: You have to rename getNavigationTreeLinkClicked()  to navigationTreeLinkClicked().